# insert/update/delete multiple tables in single SQL statement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jmeter, sql-injection

When I use JMeter with [JDBC request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) on Oracle DB it doesn't allow `;` in statement.

> SQL query.
>   Do not enter a trailing semi-colon.

For example

```
insert into a select '1' from dual;
insert into b select '1' from dual
```

Will produce exception (while it work when split to 2 separate request):

```
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

If I want to execute clear/insert of test data I can't insert multiple **tables** using 1 JDBC request and I must create at least 1 request per table (can be with multiple values per table).

Is there a way to insert/update/delete except using a callable statement ?

Is this limitation connected to solely to SQL injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert would work, using `INSERT ALL`, such as

```
insert all
  into a (col) values ('1')
  into b (col) values ('2')
select * From dual
```

Update and delete wouldn't; I'm afraid that you'll have to use one statement per table, unless you want to use PL/SQL and call a **procedure** which will do all that job.

Comment: I just answer similar, you still need to remove `;` for it to work

Comment: Well, `;` is a terminator which is OK as far as (Oracle) is concerned. If it shouldn't/can't be used in you Java program, remove it. `insert all` is what counts, I presume :) I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try : `Insert Into tableA a, tableB b Value (a.field = (Select '1' From Dual), b.field = (Select '1' From Dual))`, I'm not totally sure but I think it can work.

Comment: Different error: `ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword`, tried also `Insert Into tableA a, tableB b Values (a.field = (Select '1' From Dual), b.field = (Select '1' From Dual))`

Comment: So replace `Value` by `Values`, we're not here to do all your job !

Answer (score 0):

I found [INSERT ALL](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php) with multiple tables works:

```
INSERT ALL
 Into a (a) values ('1')
 into b (b) values('1')
 SELECT * FROM dual
```

> You can also use the INSERT ALL statement to insert multiple rows into more than one table in one command.

Answer (score 0):

The ; isn't part of "sql" it's a terminator for the program that is sending the sql. In sqldev/sqlcl/sqlplus the ";" is seen to know the end of the statement to sent everything up to that point to the database as a statement. Then process the next set of text until the next ";" or "/"

This example presents to the database as one big string such as:

> "insert into a select '1' from dual; insert into b select '1' from dual"

To perform 2 statements in 1 call to the database, it'll need a begin/end around to convert it to an executable block such as

```
BEGIN
insert into a select '1' from dual;
insert into b select '1' from dual;
END;
```

Then in JMeter change to "Callable Statement"