# Error running Oracle script in F8 and automation mode

Tags: oracle, plsql, jmeter, plsqldeveloper

I have the following problem:

I'm automating some scripts in Oracle using Jmeter.
I'm getting an error in Jmeter the same way when I use F8 to execute in PL/SQL.
F5 mode works normally.

can you help me?

Script and print below:

SELECT *FROM TABLEONE;
SELECT *FROM TABLETWO;

[image]

Why this error? Could anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you are missing a space between the asterisk and the word 'FROM'.

Comment: Even with space it doesn't work... :\ but only with F5. Running with F8 works... :\

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205396/insert-update-delete-multiple-tables-in-single-sql-statement

Comment: I don't know anything about JMeter, but in PL/SQL Developer an Explain Plan window can only explain SQL (so no semicolons) and only one statement at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is "F8", when it comes to JMeter you can only execute one statement at a time in the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler.

If you need to run 2 - either go for 2 JDBC Request samplers or switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) where you will be able to use [Statement.addBatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch(java.lang.String)) and [Statement.executeBatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) functions

Comment: It's actually an Oracle limit, not a JMeter limit. With JDBC drivers and databases that support more than one SQL command with `Statement.execute()` JMeter's JDBC request will happily run multiple commands

Comment: Would you like to give an example using Statement.execute()??

Thank you!